# Как импортировать БД созданый в версии 12c в версию 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Есть дамп БД с версии 12c. Нужно импортировать его в версию 11g.

Что мне для этого нужно?

Может установить 12c, и возможно ли поставить одновременно и 12c и 11g?
И есть ли возможность импортировать дамп, а потом экспортировать его как-то для версии 11g?

Comment: Короткий ответ на ваш вопрос "можно". Погуглите `impdp` и `expdp`.  Если будут какие то объекты использующие новшества из 12 версии, то придется их исправлять.

Comment: Если дамп уже есть, то, возможно, будут проблемы при накате на 11-ю. Насколько я знаю, надо при создании дампа явно указать, чтобы оракл сделал дамп для другой версии.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, дамп с версии 12c нельзя как есть импортировать в 11g. Будет ошибка:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39142: incompatible version number 5.1 in dump file ".../dump12.dmp"
```

Исключение - `COMPATIBLE` параметер.  Выдержка из [оф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BAA3B679-A758-4D55-9820-432D9EB83C68.htm#SUTIL110):

> In a downgrade situation, when the target release of a Data Pump-based migration is lower than the source, **the VERSION parameter should be explicitly specified to be the same version as the target.** An exception is when the target release version is the same as the value of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter on the source system; then VERSION does not need to be specified. In general however, **Data Pump import cannot read dump file sets created by an Oracle release that is newer than the current release** unless the VERSION parameter is explicitly specified.

---

Если БД источник больше недоступен, чтобы экспортировать дамп заново, то надо установить дополнително версию 12c для импорта и последующего экспорта с установленным параметром `VERSION`.

Это будет выглядеть так:

```sh
$ expdp me/me@srv/pdb1.12c version=11.2 schemas=hr \
      directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=dump12comp11.dmp logfile=expdump12.log

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
[...]
Job "ME"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Thu Jun 18 20:45:29 2020 elapsed 0 00:01:58

## copy dump file
## FIX for 12.2.0.1 - create user hr2 identified by hr2 default tablespace users; 

$ impdp me/me@srv/orcl11g exclude=user remap_schema=hr:hr2 \
      directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=dump12comp11.dmp logfile=impdump12.log

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
[...]
Job "ME"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at 21:08:14
```

---

PS Параметр `exclude=user` необходим, чтобы обойти баг в 12.2.0.1, который был исправлен в  12.2.0.2. Кроме того, с этим параметером надо создать целевую схему перед импортом.